# Show marks and max marks in a single query

Tags: mysql, sql

For example i have a table

```
Student | Marks 
A       | 50
B       | 60
C       | 70
D       | 80
```

What i want is

```
Student | Marks | MaxMarks
A       | 50    | 80
B       | 60    | 80
C       | 70    | 80
D       | 80    | 80
```

I dont want to use sub-queries/nested queries ..

Comment: Please edit your question and specify what you *do* want to use.  A subquery is quite the right answer to your question.

Comment: this is a demostration .. my actual problem is some thing else .. using sub queries for large data is making the system unstable ...

Comment: I suggest we focus on your actual problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in a most insane way without using subqueries:

```
select t.student, t.marks, max(t2.marks) as maxmarks
from table t cross join
     table t2
group by t.student, t.marks;
```

Here is a more sensible approach:

```
select t.student, t.marks, t2.maxmarks
from table t cross join
     (select max(t2.marks) as maxmarks from table t2) t2;
```